# 1 php constant not working, the rest are fine?

Tags: php, sql, constants, defined

I've had this problem before but couldn't find a solution and my host wont offer support.

I've got a load of constants defined for my website in a included file...mostly for sql table names...1 works..the other says the constant is not defined.

```
define("TBL_PRODUCT_IMAGES", "ecom_product_images");
define("TBL_SECTION_IMAGES", "ecom_section_images");
```

Just for troubleshooting i've created a basic check in a website page which is linked to other scripts including the file containing the constants;

```
if (defined('TBL_SECTION_IMAGES')) {
    echo "Section images defined<br />";
}else{
    echo "Section images NOT defined<br />";
}
if (defined('TBL_PRODUCT_IMAGES')) {
    echo "Product images defined<br />";
}else{
    echo "Product images NOT defined<br />";
}
```

and upon running the code...it says that TBL_SECTION_IMAGES is NOT set, but TBL_PRODUCT_IMAGES IS set.

The table is fine because if it use the actual table name instead of the constant my queries run fine...does the constant name conflict somewhere?

I've got around 40 constants.....ALL work fine appart from this new one....i've checked for spelling, spaces....tried moving it to the start of the list...to the end....just cant figure it out.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. I just ran the following code on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and both are defined.

Comment: Sanity check your files.. delete the contents of one entirely and see if stuff still works. If it does, you're editing the wrong files or you have a deployment problem. There's no way your example is valid or exposing some php bug.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache?

Comment: Hi, its a shared hosting server so not sure what access i've got in that area....i'll try a few other things and get back....its an odd problem though.

Comment: Are the two defines in the same file, to rule out one file being included and the other not? Try erasing the offending define and carefully retyping it -- maybe you've got an "invisible" character in the name part (zero width space, or control code).

Comment: yes the defines are all declared in 1 file...along with about 40 others which are all working fine...very odd...if i run the check on my main website pages it shows both constants are set....yet when i run the code in the admin area of my website...only 1 shows as set....however the constants file is linked up to both areas of the website.

Comment: Did you retype the offending define, to make sure there are no hidden characters that accidentally got in? Did you check to make sure that constant is not un-defined elsewhere? Did you double check that you are invoking this constant with the correct name, and there are no typos _there_?

Comment: Tried all of the above short of a server restar but to no avail...deleted the constants file...website stopped working..so its the coorect file...retyped from scratch...still not working...changed table name and constant name etc to match...still not working....going to try re-creating the table from scratch and creating a new constant.....there isn't a low limit to the number of possible constants is there?

Comment: At this point, the only thing I can think of is that somewhere later you unset or undefine that particular constant.

Comment: @PhilPerry How do you undefine or even edit a constant in php?

Comment: Supposedly it's possible to undefine a constant with one of the runkit_* calls. It might even be possible to redefine a constant using a similar method. Not your normal PHP usage, though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved....i dont know how but there was a copy of my constants file in a parent directory that shouldn't have been there....it was an older copy...although this file wasn't actually linked anywhere in the site the server was still loading it somehow?

I only noticed because i re-deleted the constants file...refreshed the web page and it still loaded everything indicating it was using another constants file...however when i deleted it yesterday the site stopped working.

Thanks for your help.